# Excel VBA macro to filter records 

Tags: filter, excel, vba

I have an excel file, In the first sheet it has data like total count with status `active` is 59 rows status `obsolete` 10 rows.
In the second sheet with 59 records with status column like `ACTIVE` AND `OBSOLETE`.

I want to create a macro to select records by clicking a button it has to filter records  `ACTIVE` or `OBSOLETE` using VBA.

Comment: So, what's the question? And why the non-specific title? Who on Earth upvoted this?! -1

Answer (score 1):

One way to auto generate the VBA code is to **record a macro** of the steps you would take to do this if you were just working directly in the workbook.  After you have the macro recorded you can look at the VBA code generated by the macro and modify as necessary.

**To record a new macro:**

- Go to the **View Tab** then **Macros** then **Record Macro**.

**To view the macro VBA code:**

- Go to the **View Tab** then **Macros** then **View Macros** then select the macro you want to view and click edit.

Hope this help you get started.

Enjoy!