# How do you select the entire excel sheet with Range using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I found a similar solution to this question in c# [How to Select all the cells in a worksheet in Excel.Range object of c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850738/how-to-select-the-whole-excel-sheet-in-excel-range-object-of-c)

What is the process to do this in VBA?

I select data normally by using "ctrl+shift over arrow, down arrow" to select an entire range of cells. When I run this in a macro it codes out A1:Q398247930, for example. I need it to just be

```
.SetRange Range("A1:whenever I run out of rows and columns")
```

I could easily do it myself without a macro, but I'm trying to make the entire process a macro, and this is just a piece of it.

```
Sub sort()
    'sort Macro
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B2"), _
      SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:whenever I run out of rows and columns")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

**edit:**
There are other parts where I might want to use the same code but the range is say "C3:End of rows & columns". Is there a way in VBA to get the location of the last cell in the document?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I believe you want to find the current region of A1 and surrounding cells - not necessarily all cells on the sheet.
If so - simply use...
**Range("A1").CurrentRegion**

Comment: Interestingly, if you have just copied a worksheet into a new workbook, **Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address** returns "A1", not the used region on the worksheet. I had to use chancea's method of **Range(Cells.Address)**, instead.

Answer (score 24):

You can simply use `cells.select` to select **all** cells in the worksheet.  You can get a valid address by saying `Range(Cells.Address)`.

If you want to find the last `Used Range` where you have made some formatting change or entered a value into you can call `ActiveSheet.UsedRange` and select it from there.  Hope that helps.

Comment: You don't even need `Cells.Select` if you just want the range. `Cells` alone will give you the range.

Comment: Well that crashed my workbook, lol, I expect it worked and was just ridiculously resource intensive. Save before running!

Answer (score 18):

you can use all cells as a object like this :

```
Dim x as Range
Set x = Worksheets("Sheet name").Cells
```

X is now a range object that contains the entire worksheet

Answer (score 9):

you have a few options here:

1. Using the UsedRange property
2. find the last row and column used
3. use a mimic of shift down and shift right

I personally use the Used Range and find last row and column method most of the time.

Here's how you would do it using the UsedRange property:

```
Sheets("Sheet_Name").UsedRange.Select
```

This statement will select all used ranges in the worksheet, note that sometimes this doesn't work very well when you delete columns and rows.

The alternative is to find the very last cell used in the worksheet

```
Dim rngTemp As Range
Set rngTemp = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
If Not rngTemp Is Nothing Then
    Range(Cells(1, 1), rngTemp).Select
End If
```

What this code is doing:

1. Find the last cell containing any value
2. select cell(1,1) all the way to the last cell

Comment: hi, yes this will catch cells last used no matter how many empty rows you have in between =]

Comment: Should be `Dim rngTemp As Range`

Comment: Yep, I typically use `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select` to select all cells used (including any blank ones within the range).

Answer (score 4):

Another way to select all cells within a range, as long as the data is contiguous, is to use `Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Select`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend recording a macro, like found in this post;

[Excel VBA macro to filter records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469228/excel-vba-macro-to-filter-records)

But if you are looking to find the end of your data and not the end of the workbook necessary, if there are not empty cells between the beginning and end of your data, I often use something like this;

```
R = 1
Do While Not IsEmpty(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(R, 1))
    R = R + 1
Loop
Range("A5:A" & R).Select 'This will give you a specific selection
```

You are left with R = to the number of the row after your data ends. This could be used for the column as well, and then you could use something like Cells(C , R).Select, if you made C the column representation.

Comment: Same clarification that I asked Derek.

Would this catch the case where I have an empty row in between the last row?

Comment: No, this would stop when it got to an empty cell.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub SelectAllCellsInSheet(SheetName As String)
    lastCol = Sheets(SheetName).Range("a1").End(xlToRight).Column
    Lastrow = Sheets(SheetName).Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    Sheets(SheetName).Range("A1", Sheets(SheetName).Cells(Lastrow, lastCol)).Select
End Sub
```

**To use with ActiveSheet:**

```
Call SelectAllCellsInSheet(ActiveSheet.Name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I used, I know it could use some perfecting, but I think it will help others...

```
''STYLING''

Dim sheet As Range

' Find Number of rows used
Dim Final As Variant
    Final = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

' Find Last Column
Dim lCol As Long
    lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Final & "", Cells(1, lCol ))
With sheet
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 1
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the Worksheet ".UsedRange" method is superior in many instances to solve this problem.
I struggled with a truncation issue that is a normal behaviour of the ".CurrentRegion" method. Using [ Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion ] does not yield the results I desired when the worksheet consists of one column with blanks in the rows (and the blanks are wanted).  In this case, the ".CurrentRegion" will truncate at the first record.  I implemented a work around but recently found an even better one; see code below that allows copying the whole set to another sheet or to identify the actual address (or just rows and columns):

```
Sub mytest_GetAllUsedCells_in_Worksheet()
    Dim myRange

    Set myRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
    'Alternative code:  set myRange = activesheet.UsedRange

   'use msgbox or debug.print to show the address range and counts
   MsgBox myRange.Address      
   MsgBox myRange.Columns.Count
   MsgBox myRange.Rows.Count

  'Copy the Range of data to another sheet
  'Note: contains all the cells with that are non-empty
   myRange.Copy (Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1"))
   'Note:  transfers all cells starting at "A1" location.  
   '       You can transfer to another area of the 2nd sheet
   '       by using an alternate starting location like "C5".

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might work:

Sh.Range("A1", Sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

Answer (score 0):

Refering to the very first question, I am looking into the same.
The result I get, recording a macro, is, starting by selecting cell A76:

```
Sub find_last_row()
    Range("A76").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
End Sub
```